# Drupal Console Installation: The "phar.readonly" setting needs to be off to create Phars

Tags: 8

I am trying to install the [Drupal Console](http://drupalconsole.com/) for Drupal 8 on Linux Mint 17.1. During the installation I am getting the following warning notice:

`[ ] Notice: The "phar.readonly" setting needs to be off to create Phars.`

Any idea how to solve this? Will this effect the console operation?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This is a plain PHP question, since _phar.readonly_ is a PHP directive and Drupal doesn't change how it works or how it is set.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your php.ini:

```
phar.readonly = Off
```

It won't affect the console's operation (unless it needs to create phars at some point, in which case it now can, whereas it couldn't before).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it won't affect the console operation; the message will be removed on the next release since the installer has been changed.

And you can remove the warning by doing what Clive mentioned.